# Disable adding xform-visited for specific element

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Is it possible to unbind event for adding xforms-visited class to specific element of form?

I have one collapsible section (initially closed) with only one paragraph and I need it to remain closed after validation, but it gets xforms-visited and fr-section-open classes if something on form doesn't pass validation. Maybe it could be also related to binding opening sections if data on form is invalid.

FYI - I'm using Orbeon 2016.3 version

Comment: You're saying you have a collapsed section, and on save you would like the section to stay collapsed even if it contains an error? But users could click on the error in the error summary, and this would open the section, and set the focus on the field with the error. Is that indeed what you're looking for?

Comment: I needed element looking like accordion inside my form so I have used collapsible behaviour of section for displaying some text in it - I have used only text input inside it (configure it with not required and hid the input field on frontend so I could have only text displayed). The section is initally closed but could be opened on user interaction. But when it is closed and the form gets validate if there is any error this section opens although i have no need to fill real input.

Comment: Thank you for the additional details, but I'm still not fully understanding your situation. You're saying that users don't need to provide a value for that field, yet the field is marked as invalid. So it looks to me like the field shouldn't be marked as invalid, shouldn't it? If not, why do you need to have that specific validation on the field? Would should it kick in, if not when you're saving or submitting the data?

Comment: I have a section which contains only an output field and that section is initially closed. A user can expand the section by clicking on it. But when the user tries to submit the form which is not valid the section I mentioned expands. This is not behavior I would like, I would like to section stay closed  if upon submiting the form this section was not expanded.

I have made a gif of the currrent behaviour
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gppyd0f053uat5/2018-01-25_18h10_17.gif?dl=0

Comment: Got it, I now see what you mean: if any field is invalid, when saving *all* the sections are automatically opened, while it would be enough to open just those sections that contain invalid controls. I think you're making a good point here :). We'll discuss this internally, and I'll then follow-up here with a comment, most likely early next week.

Comment: Yes, I suppose if every section was collapsible that it would open each one of them no matter if they have invalid controls or not. Im keeping fingers crossed for solution :)

Comment: I created a request for enhancement per your suggestion, and posted a reply below. We'll hopefully get a chance to implement this soon.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Because I needed to solve it somehow, I have manipulated with those sections using custom js and css, so I have covered it for now. But will keep the track of this request so I could update it in a better way when the time comes. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: Got it Jovona, and I'll also try to comment here when there is something new related to this.

Comment: Here we go: this is now implemented, and will ship in Orbeon Forms 2018.1. I've updated my response below, and it also contains a link to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orbeon Forms 2018.1 and newer only expands sections that contains errors. This is done with the new [`expand-invalid` action](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html).

Until Orbeon Forms 2017.2, all the sections expand when an error is encountered.